# Tracking logged in users vs guest users

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm looking at how we can separate out Google Analytics reporting between guest users and logged in users to view engagement between the two states. Does Google Analytics have any built-in way of doing this?

There is a logout link that shows when a user is logged in:

```
<a id="a-logout" href="https://www.matthewclarklive.com/home.aspx?logout" class="sitetoplink logout"><img src="https://www.matthewclarklive.com/images/topnav/login.gif" border="0" align="absmiddle" class="keyicon"> Logout Now</a>
```

Could this be used in a variable or javascript of some kind to indicate whether a customer is logged in or not?

Appreciate any advice!

Answer (score 0):

A solution could be send to Google Analytics a [custom dimension](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709829?hl=en) (hit level) that contains two different string, `loggedIn` or `loggedOut`, for all user interactions respectively when the user is logged in and when he is not. Then you can use that dimension in your reports.